# Creating UNIX safe test in PHP from windows

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to use PHP to create a shell script on Windows. It's part of some larger functionality.

Here's my script:

```
$contents_str = ''.
'#!/bin/bash
yes | apt-get update
yes | apt-get upgrade
useradd sudoer -g sudo -s /bin/bash -m
echo "sudoer:sudoerpass" | chpasswd';
```

However, when this file gets on the server, I get a "bad interpreter - no such file or directory" error. I know it's because I have some hidden windows characters in the file.

Is there a function or script I can use to remove hidden windows characters in PHP? Alternatively, is there a single bash command I can use to do this on the server?

I've used dos2unix on the file and it works after I do this, but I'd rather not use dos2unix because it's something I'd have to install on the server and I need something I can use right out of the Ubuntu box.

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

I just found a way to clean up the string using preg_replace.

Here's the code (of course, continuing from the code I already posted above):

```
$contents_nixsafe_str = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\r|\n)/s', "\n" , $contents_str);
```

This worked without any issues for me.

Thanks for all the responses

Comment: Don't use windows?  /me laughs  But your text editor should have an option for Unix compatible line breaks. I would look into that and make sure it is using them.

Comment: @Brad: I use Notepad++ when I want to write shell scripts and don't have any issues. However, in this instance I need the shell script content to be in PHP (Using Zend Studio 8 for that).

Comment: Never used it, but either or there should be a setting to set the linebreaks to UNIX style as appose to Windows. Coding around that, to me, would be bad practice. Better to fix the problem at the source and not hack around it. But to each their own. For some assistance for Zend Studio, I found this http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=2158  and this  http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=3799   I am not sure why Zend would make such a blunder, but oh well.

Comment: @Brad: I understand. I was really keen to find a way to do this using pure PHP and I just found something with preg_replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using an editor that outputs line-ending (EOL) characters in Windows's CRLF format. Depending on the editor, you may be able to tell it to use UNIX line endings (LF) instead.

Alternatively, you can concatenate the lines together and manually append the EOL character:

```
$contents_str = ''
  .'#!/bin/bash'."\n"
  .'yes | apt-get update'."\n"
  .'yes | apt-get upgrade'."\n"
  .'useradd sudoer -g sudo -s /bin/bash -m'."\n"
  .'echo "sudoer:sudoerpass" | chpasswd';
```

It's ugly, but gets the job done.

Comment: I'll take ugly over not-working any day pal. Thanks a lot, this did it for me. I don't have any issues when I create the shell scripts in my text editor (Notepad++), but in this case I needed to have it embedded in PHP code. So your suggestion worked like a charm.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the editor you use to write the PHP script is what was likely causing the issue in the first place.  Glad I could be of help though.

Comment: I'm using Zend Studio 8. I just found a way to do this using preg_replace, I'll post the code shortly.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing newlines with the system newline constant

```
$contents_str = str_replace("\r\n", PHP_EOL, $contents_str);
```

Also, you may want to look at [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax for creating multiline strings, where you start and end a string with a special identifier (in this example `STR`):

```
$contents_str = <<<STR
#!/bin/bash
yes | apt-get update
yes | apt-get upgrade
useradd sudoer -g sudo -s /bin/bash -m
echo "sudoer:sudoerpass" | chpasswd
STR;
```

Comment: I tried both of these but they didn't work, not sure why. Thanks a lot for the suggestion though, I've learned something new with the heredoc syntax.

Comment: That's interesting. Maybe the replace should look for `\r` or `\n`, not both. `PHP_EOL` should be the correct line ending on the machine the script is running on. Best of luck with it anyway.

Comment: Ok. Did that again but it still didn't work. I'm not sure str_replace is the right function to use. I found something with preg_replace which I've posted above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$contents_arr = array
(
    '#!/bin/bash',
    'yes | apt-get update',
    'yes | apt-get upgrade',
    'useradd sudoer -g sudo -s /bin/bash -m',
    'echo "sudoer:sudoerpass" | chpasswd'
);

$contents_str = implode("\n", $contents_arr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this but it doesn't work. I still see ^M when I open the file using cat -v.